# Python pandas/numpy fill 1 to cells with value, and zero to cells of nan

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an array with cells of different types of data (String, float, Integer, ...) .

e.g.

```
[[18 '1/4/11' 73.0 'Male' 4.0]
 [18    nan   73.0 'Male' nan]
 [18 '7/5/11' 73.0 'Male' 7.0]]
```

And I want to assign 0 to cells with value `nan`, and 1 to all others

expected outcome:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1
  1 0 1 1 0
  1 1 1 1 1]]
```

With pandas's `fillna(0)`, I'm able to fill `nan` with 0, but how to assign 1 to all the cells with available values given that the data is of different types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create boolean mask and cast to integer:

```
~(np.isnan(arr)).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
 pd.notnull(arr).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's a dataframe or an ndarray, you can use `pd.notnull`:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[18, '1/4/11', 73.0, 'Male', 4.0],
...                 [18,    np.nan,   73.0, 'Male', np.nan],
...                 [18, '7/5/11', 73.0, 'Male', 7.0]], dtype=object)
>>> pd.notnull(arr)
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```